# GitlabCi. Action "on_stop" not always executed

Tags: devops, gitlab-ci

Sorry for my English.

Stop environment job ("stop on deployment server") exists only when I create commit into the "develop" branch. If I do merge request then execute job "deploy to deployments server using ansible", but the job "stop on deployment server" not created and I can not execute manually.
I don't understand, why (
Have a simple file .gitlab-ci.yml.

```
.base_rules: &base_rules
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "develop" && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      when: on_success
    - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "master" && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      when: on_success
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develop" && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"'
      when: on_success
    - when: never

deploy to deployments server using ansible:
   stage: deploy_to_deployments
   image: williamyeh/ansible:ubuntu18.04
   <<: *base_rules
   environment:
     name: push_on_deployments_server/$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA
     url: https://deployment.mydomain.com/deploy/$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA/html/
     on_stop: stop on deployment server

stop on deployment server:
  stage: deploy_to_deployments
  image: williamyeh/ansible:ubuntu18.04
  environment:
    name: push_on_deployments_server/$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA
    action: stop
  when: manual
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
```

Thanks for any comments

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. I created another rule for the job with stop action. I wrote this code:

```
.base_rules_stop: &base_rules_stop
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "develop" && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      when: manual
    - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "master" && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      when: manual
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develop" && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"'
      when: manual
    - when: never

~~~
stop on deployment server:
  stage: deploy_to_deployments
  image: williamyeh/ansible:ubuntu18.04
  environment:
    name: push_on_deployments_server/$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA
    action: stop
  <<: *base_rules_stop
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
```

And now I always have stop action already, after merge request and after push into the develop branch. I don't know why that is it. Because at the original code I writing "when:manual" and in rules too.
But now it works and I glad it.

Comment: what does the & mean in &base_rules? i never seen in docs where one uses these &*****

Comment: This is a feature of the YAML format. The anchor is called.

Comment: what is the point of it? never used it so not sure what i am missing

Comment: So sorry for the late answer. As for me, I am using anchors for excluding double code. For example, If I have one rule for more than one place.

Comment: reference is better than anchor